# Safariでmp3ファイルの一時停止再生がうまくできない

Tags: javascript, html5, safari

html5のaudioを使って、ブラウザ上で音声ファイルを再生するプログラムを作成しております。

複数ファイルを連続して再生する必要があるため、ファイルを結合し、ブラウザで読み込ませていますが、safariで一時停止からの再生が正常に動作しない事象が発生しました。

mp3ファイルの結合は、単純結合（下記linuxコマンド）にて作成しております。
`$ cat a.mp3 b.mp3 > c.mp3`

ソースコードは以下となります。

test.js ※一部抜粋

```
var lastSoundFile; // 最後に再生した音声（停止、再生に利用）

//音声再生処理
function playSound(){
    var playSoundFile = new Audio();
    if(playSoundFile.canPlayType("audio/mpeg")) {
        playSoundFile.src = 'c.mp3';
    }
    //再生
    playSoundFile.addEventListener('canplay', function(){
        playSoundFile.play();
    }, true);

    //デバッグ
    $("body").append($("<div />").attr('id','test'));
    playSoundFile.addEventListener('timeupdate',     function(){
    playSoundFile.duration = 125.15265306122448;
        $("#test").html('<br>position : '+playSoundFile.currentTime
        +'<br>duration : '+playSoundFile.duration
        +'<br>volume : '+playSoundFile.volume
        +'<br>paused : '+playSoundFile.paused);
    }, true);
    playSoundFile.load();
    lastSoundFile = playSoundFile;
}

//コントロール
function operation(action){
    if(action == "pause"){
        lastSoundFile.pause();
    }else if(action == "play"){
        lastSoundFile.play();
    }
}
```

test.html ※一部抜粋

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="start">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="playSound();">start</a>
</div>

<div id="control">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="operation('play');">再生</a> | 
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="operation('pause');">一時停止</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

上記にアクセスしstartを押すと音声が再生され、一時停止と再生が行えます。

Safariでアクセスして、一時停止、再生を行うと、
結合前のa.mp3のパートが再生されているときは正常に動作するのですが、
b.mp3のパートが再生されているときに一時停止、再生をすると初めから再生されてしまいます。

デバッグで表示しているdurationの値が、Safariの場合のみなぜかa.mp3の再生時間が表示されていることが原因だと思うのですが、こちらの解決方法がわかりません。

環境は以下となります。
MacOSX 10.10.3
Safari 8.0.6

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3):

Safariでの再生を試す前に、まずは通常のオーディオプレイヤーでその`c.mp3`の`b.mp3`の部分を正常に再生できるか試してみてください。
<strike>おそらくSafariに限らずどんなプレイヤーでも正常に再生できないはずです。</strike>

<strike>MP3形式のオーディオファイルは`cat`のような単純な結合では結合できません

(というか、`cat`で正しく結合できるのはプレーンテキストファイルくらいで、

ほとんどのフォーマットのファイルは`cat`では正しく結合できません)。

`b.mp3`の部分が再生できないのは、単純にファイルが壊れているからです。</strike>
正しくオーディオファイルを結合するには、Audacityのようなオーディオ編集ソフトを使う方法があります。

(追記) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3 によれば、MP3ファイルは全体がMP3フレームの繰り返しだけで構成されているため、単純なバイナリでの結合でもちゃんと再生できるファイルになるようです。質問者さんから指摘があったとおり、`cat`で結合しても再生は出来ないというのは間違いです。

ただし、理由は不明ですが`cat`で結合したオーディオファイルをちゃんと再生できないプレイヤーもあるようで、自分の試した範囲ではWindows上のChromeで正しく再生出来ていません。特定のブラウザの実装の問題のように思えますし、差し当たっての回避策としてはオーディオ編集ソフトで結合するのがいいと思います。

Comment: Hibiya Ryuto様

回答ありがとうございます。
catは私も半信半疑でしたが、ネットで見つけ試したところ、通常のオーディオプレイヤーで再生できております。もちろん該当Macのitunesでも再生出来ました。
また、他ブラウザも問題なしでMacのsafariのみダメという状況です。

Comment: そのとおりですね。驚きましたが、再生はできるようです。ただ、c.mp3をChromeで再生してみると、やはり曲の長さを正しく読み取れていないようで、確かに後半部分を途中から再生することができません。どうも対応している実装とそうでない実装があるようです

Answer (score 0):

SoundJS or Web Audio
windowsSafariはノーサポートみたいです

https://github.com/CreateJS/SoundJS/issues/60

Comment: kawa様

回答ありがとうございます。
Macのsafariとなります。
もしMacでなにか情報ごさいましたらご教示頂けますと幸いです。